# Query Windows Server DNS records by an ip address

Tags: domain-name-system

I'm looking for a way to query DNS records for a zone based on an IP address and can't seem to find a way to do this... any suggestions?

I have one zone with hundreds of records having different IP addresses.  Many match a certain ip and I want to get all records that match the ip I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no valid PTR records, you can try the following:

> `dnscmd [dns_server] /enumrecords zone.name @ | findstr "ww.xx.yy.zz"`

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a "reverse" DNS lookup, which may or may not work depending on whether or not a proper reverse zone has been set up for the netblock in question and if there is a `PTR` record for this IP address.

If there *is* a valid PTR record for the IP, you can test for it using `host`:

```
~ host serverfault.com
serverfault.com has address 198.252.206.16
serverfault.com mail is handled by 30 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
serverfault.com mail is handled by 40 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
serverfault.com mail is handled by 50 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
serverfault.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
serverfault.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
~ host 198.252.206.16
16.206.252.198.in-addr.arpa domain name pointer stackoverflow.com.
```

Comment: Windows doesn't have `host`; only `nslookup`.

Comment: Also nslookup will resolve PTR records.
Windows does have nslookup.